# How to create/get custom attribute element in html by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have element same below:

```
<div cutomsAttr.option1.option2="abc" id="custom">
</div>
```

I want to create and get custom attribute containing modifiers, if any.

For example in `cutomsAttr.option1.option2`, the modifiers object would be

```
{ option1: true, option2: true }.
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible using plain javascript but you can use custom data attributes to get something similar.

Comment: Thank you @palaѕн for response

Comment: If you want I can share an example using custom data attributes as an answer to help you get an idea.

Comment: I'm curious about this, please help me thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes, which allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes or extra properties on DOM.

The syntax is simple. Any attribute on any element whose attribute name starts with `data-` is a data attribute. Lets say you have a `div` and you want to store some extra information that doesn't have any visual representation. Just use `data` attributes for that like:

```
<div id="custom" data-cutomsAttr="abc">
</div>
```

Then in your code, you can access its new `data-cutomsAttr` attribute value [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property like:

```js
const custom = document.querySelector('#custom'); 
console.log( custom.dataset.cutomsattr )
```

```html
<div id="custom" data-cutomsAttr="abc">
</div>
```

**Note:** That camelCase attribute `cutomsAttr` are converted to lowercase `cutomsattr`.

---

Now, in order to get something solar to "*Custom attribute containing modifiers*", you can just set multiple `data` attributes for the options like:

```
<div id="custom" data-cutomsAttr="abc" data-option1="true" data-option2="false">
</div>
```

and then access them like:

```js
const custom = document.querySelector('#custom'); 
const { cutomsattr, option1, option2 } = custom.dataset
console.log( cutomsattr, option1, option2 )
```

```html
<div id="custom" data-cutomsAttr="abc" data-option1="true" data-option2="false">
</div>
```

---

In case, if you don't want to set `data-option1` & `data-option2` all divs and make them optional with default value `false`, you can also do that like:

```js
const custom = document.querySelector('#custom'); 
const { cutomsattr, option1 = false, option2 = false } = custom.dataset
console.log( cutomsattr, option1, option2 )
```

```html
<div id="custom" data-cutomsAttr="abc" data-option1="true">
</div>
```